# Is one of these statements preferred over the other?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is either of these questions incorrect, or defective in any way? If so, can you explain why?

1. "This answer is assuming that you are concerned with ..."
2. "This answer assumes you are concerned with ..."

Comment: "Preferred" is the archetypal "opinion-based" question, and "Is either incorrect?" is [proof-reading](/help/on-topic#:~:text=How%20can%20I%20ask%20about%20checking%20my%20text%3F). To use "is assuming" seems characteristic of Indian English, and appears to make it more obvious that the *answer* is doing the assuming rather than its writer, but that doesn't make it wrong. (2) also gets the answer to do the assuming. Please consider exactly what you're asking about — Why do you think either might be wrong? — and adjust your question to ask about that.

Comment: Thanks - I revised & requested a review.

Comment: It's still proof-reading. What has prompted you to ask the question? Please read the linked help.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know where to go from here. It seemed like a straightforward Q to me. That's OK - I'll live without it.